# Magento 2 : How to improve ajax call?

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery

I am making a ajax call in folowing way:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){

$("#test1").change(function(){
    var test1Value = document.getElementById("test1").value;
    var test1Label = $("#test1 option:selected").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'test_controller_url',/* assume */
        data: ('test1='+test1Value+'&test1Label='+test1Label),
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        showLoader: true,
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert("success");
        $("#test2").html(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        alert("failure");
  });
});
```

In controller:

```
public function execute()
{
    echo "test";exit;
}
```

Then ajax call completing after 5 sec.
How can I optimize that time.

Used latest jquery.
Magento version : 2.1.5.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting response from controller **from 5 sec**?

Comment: @AmitBera Yes  .

Comment: I am getting the same problem any solution?